# Is it possible to have an array of elements as a property of a PHP class?

Tags: php

As this does not seam to work?

```
class Site {
private $PROPERTIES = array(
           "NAME",'STACKOVERFLOW',
                   "URL",'http:/stackoverflow.com'
                  );


    function __construct() {
            $this->props = $PROPERTIES;
    }
    function dumpData() {
            var_dump($this->props)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can but you missed the way of referencing properties...

instead use:

```
$this->props = $this->PROPERTIES;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want it a associative array?

```
private $PROPERTIES = array(
           "NAME" => 'STACKOVERFLOW',
           "URL" => 'http:/stackoverflow.com'
                  );
```

At least that is how I understood it.
Because that would work.

```
$this->PROPERTIES['NAME'];
```

** fixed, thanks guys :P Too early for me...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need $props since you already have $PROPERTIES...

Answer (score 0):

In classes, reference class-level variables from functions using `$this` :

```
function __construct() {
        $this->props = $this->PROPERTIES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function __construct() {
        $this->props = $this->PROPERTIES;
}
```